# Blurry text with drawString in Slick 2D

Tags: java, slick2d

I have this wierd problem with my slick 2d game not rendering the `graphics.drawString();`
properly unless I'm in full screen mode.

**Screenshot**:
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bGol.png)

This is my code so far (This is basicly just the "Simple Game" tutorial.)

**Declaration**:

```
public Font font;
public TrueTypeFont trueTypeFont;
```

**init**:

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc) 
        throws SlickException {
    font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);
    trueTypeFont = new TrueTypeFont(font, true);

}
```

**render**:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) 
        throws SlickException 
{
    // render some text to the screen
    trueTypeFont.drawString(20.0f, 20.0f, "Slick displaying True Type Fonts", Color.green);
    g.drawString("Hello", 300,300);
}
```

I have tried setting VSync to true, and also limiting the framerate manually. But nope, no change.

Any ideas why this is happening? It renders the text perfectly in fullscreen mode.

Comment: EDIT: It's actually ALL the graphics that get's corrupted when not in full screen mode. Even simple drawn images looks the same way.